# Like Bezout's identity but with Natural numbers and an arbitrary constant. Can it be solved?

Tags: math, discrete

I'm an amateur playing with discrete math. This isn't a
homework problem though I am doing it at home.

I want to solve ax + by = c for natural numbers, with a, b and c
given and x and y to be computed.  I want to find all x, y pairs
that will satisfy the equation.

This has a similar structure to Bezout's identity for integers
where there are multiple (infinite?) solution pairs. I thought
the similarity might mean that the extended Euclidian algorithm
could help here.  Below are two implementations of the EEA that
seem to work; they're both adapted from code found on the net.

Could these be adapted to the task, or perhaps can someone
find a more promising avenue?

```cpp
typedef long int Int;

#ifdef RECURSIVE_EEA
Int // returns the GCD of a and b and finds x and y 
// such that ax + by == GCD(a,b), recursively
eea(Int a, Int b, Int &x, Int &y) {
    if (0==a) {
        x = 0;
        y = 1;
        return b;
    }
    Int x1; x1=0;
    Int y1; y1=0;
    Int gcd = eea(b%a, a, x1, y1);
    x = y1 - b/a*x1;
    y = x1;
    return gcd;
}
#endif

#ifdef ITERATIVE_EEA
Int // returns the GCD of a and b and finds x and y 
// such that ax + by == GCD(a,b), iteratively
eea(Int a, Int b, Int &x, Int &y) {
    x = 0;
    y = 1; 
    Int u; u=1;
    Int v; v=0;         // does this need initialising?
    Int q;              // quotient
    Int r;              // remainder
    Int m;
    Int n;
    while (0!=a) {      
        q = b/a;        // quotient
        r = b%a;        // remainder
        m = x - u*q;    // ??  what are the invariants?
        n = y - v*q;    // ??  When does this overflow?
        b = a;          // A candidate for the gcd - a's last nonzero value.
        a = r;          // a becomes the remainder - it shrinks each time.
                        // When a hits zero, the u and v that are written out
                        // are final values and the gcd is a's previous value.
        x = u;          // Here we have u and v shuffling values out
        y = v;          // via x and y. If a has gone to zero, they're final.
        u = m;          // ... and getting new values
        v = n;          // from m and n
    }
    return b;
}
#endif
```

Comment: This would be better suited to https://math.stackexchange.com (not least because people answering there will be able to make use of TeX-like markup). But yes, you can use the extended Euclidean algorithm here. If `gcd(a,b)` does not divide `c`, there are no solutions; if `g=gcd(a, b)` divides `c` then you can simply scale `x` and `y` by `c/g` in a solution to `ax + by = g` to get a solution to `ax + by = c`. You can then adjust in the same way as for the EEA to parameterize all solutions, and use the nonnegativy conditions on `x` and `y` to cut down possible parameter values to a finite range.

Comment: Thanks Mark.  I'm new here, and was beginning to think that I wasn't going to get any replies.  I also found that, at least in integers, that this was a solved problem. The Wolfram MathWorld site and Wikipedia both have pages called Diophantine Equation that cover this for integers.

Answer (score 0):

If we slightly change the equation form:

```
ax + by = c
by = c - ax
y =  (c - ax)/b
```

Then we can loop `x` through all numbers in its range (`a*x <= c`) and compute if viable natural `y` exists. So no there is not infinite number of solutions the limit is `min(c/a,c/b)` ... Here small C++ example of naive solution:

```cpp
int a=123,b=321,c=987654321;
int x,y,ax;
for (x=1,ax=a;ax<=c;x++,ax+=a)
    {
    y = (c-ax)/b;
    if (ax+(b*y)==c) here output x,y solution somewhere;
    }
```

If you want to speed this up then just iterate `y` too and just check if `c-ax` is divisible by `b` Something like this:

```cpp
int a=123,b=321,c=987654321;
int x,y,ax,cax,by;
for (x=1,ax=a,y=(c/b),by=b*y;ax<=c;x++,ax+=a)
    {
    cax=c-ax;
    while (by>cax){ by-=b; y--; if (!y) break; }
    if (by==cax) here output x,y solution somewhere;
    }
```

As you can see now both `x,y` are iterated in opposite directions in the same loop and no division or multiplication is present inside loop anymore so its much faster here first few results:

```
      method1         method2
 [  78.707 ms] |  [  21.277 ms] // time needed for computation
         75044 |          75044 // found solutions
-------------------------------
    75,3076776 |     75,3076776 // first few solutions in x,y order
   182,3076735 |    182,3076735
   289,3076694 |    289,3076694
   396,3076653 |    396,3076653
   503,3076612 |    503,3076612
   610,3076571 |    610,3076571
   717,3076530 |    717,3076530
   824,3076489 |    824,3076489
   931,3076448 |    931,3076448
  1038,3076407 |   1038,3076407
  1145,3076366 |   1145,3076366
```

I expect that for really huge `c` and small `a,b` numbers this

```
while (by>cax){ by-=b; y--; if (!y) break; }
```

might be slower than actual division using GCD ...

Comment: I hadn't looked at it like that. Thanks for taking the time to post. I somehow think that using the Extended Euclidian Algorithm once to generate a single solution then iterating over a parameter like the Wikipedia article suggests would be faster, but I may be wrong.

Comment: @Graemec depends on the magnitude ... `c/a` and `c/b` ... btw I am sure I have some answer about GCD approach for this too but can not find it anymore (maybe deleted question)